# How to define variable with generic type argument?

Tags: generics, typescript, lambda

Consider the following code to define a React component with a generic type argument `TRow`:

```js
function DataTable<TRow> ({ rows: TRow[] }) {
  return (
  )
}
```

In previous code, ES6 was used and components were defined as stateless functions:

```
const DataTable = ({ rows }) => ( ... )
```

How can I define such a function so that it has a generic type argument `TRow`? Is this supported by Typescript at all?

Comment: I totally got your question wrong, I don't see why you want a function to be on a constant. Maybe you can just do public static yourFunction<T>(somearg:T) {} ???

Comment: Yes, like I showed in the question, I can define it using `function DataTable<TRow> ...`. However, since all code uses code like `const DataTable = ...` I thought it would be nice to keep that same syntax, but add the generic somehow.

Comment: Your function signature is wrong. `({ rows: TRow[] })` is renamed destructuring and wrong one. Type must be written this way `({ rows } : { rows: TRow[]})` https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9657

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, but only for Functions, not any arbitrary variable.
As you can see, it's the type itself, where you define generics and then you can make a variable of that type, which allows it to set the generic.

These all are equivalent:

```
interface Row { a: number }

function DataTable1<T>({ rows }: { rows: T[] }): void { return void 0 }
const DataTable2: <T>({ rows }: { rows: T[] }) => void = ({rows}) => void 0
type  DataTable = <T>({ rows }: { rows: T[] }) => void
const DataTable3: DataTable = ({rows}) => void 0

const a1 = DataTable1<Row>({rows: [{a: 1}]})
const a2 = DataTable2<Row>({rows: [{a: 2}]})
const a3 = DataTable3<Row>({rows: [{a: 3}]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can exactly do what you wish with typescript.

Let's assume you will wrap your prop types in a generic interface `DataTableProps` with the type parameter holder `TRow` (can be any type of row).

```
    interface DataTableProps<TRow> {
        items: Array<TRow>
    }
```

Now, you want to use that property type in your react component class. So, assuming your component is stateless, we will use `React.SFC` type to refer to a stateless react component.

```
    function getDataTableComp<TRow>() : React.SFC<DataTableProps<TRow>>{
        return props => <div>
            <p>{props.items.toString()}</p>
        </div>
    }
```

That is a function that returns a specific type of stateless react component. Then we can use the function as,

```
    const MyStringDataTable = getDataTableComp<string>();
```

Now, we have a specific data-table type, i.e., data-table of string rows. Then, we can use an instance as

```
    ReactDOM.render(<MyStringDataTable items={['a', 'b']} />, document.getElementById('page-root'))
```

You will get `a,b` rendered in your page.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the function definition you can achieve that, changing the ***function definition*** by an ***interface function definition***.

Here an example following the code that you provided above:

```
// Replace this
function DataTable<TRow> ({ rows: TRow[] }) {
    return (
    )
}

// By this

interface DataTable<TRow> {
    (elements: { rows: TRow[] }): any
}

//And now you can define the function in this way:
// (Here is necessary to use <T extends any> to avoid syntax errors when you're working on .tsx files. On .ts files <T> is enough) 
const myFn: <T>(...args: Parameters<DataTable<T>>) => ReturnType<DataTable<T>> = <T extends any>({ rows: T }) => {
    return 123;
};

// And now you call the above function:

myFn<string>({ rows: ['asd,asd'] });
```

Here I answered a question that helped to solve this problem: [Typescript ReturnType of generic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321419/typescript-returntype-of-generic-function/64840774#64840774)