# Typescript ReturnType of generic function

Tags: typescript, generics

The new `ReturnType` in [TypeScript 2.8](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-inference-in-conditional-types) is a really useful feature that lets you extract the return type of a particular function.

```
function foo(e: number): number {
    return e;
}

type fooReturn = ReturnType<typeof foo>; // number
```

However, I'm having trouble using it in the context of generic functions.

```
function foo<T>(e: T): T {
    return e;
}

type fooReturn = ReturnType<typeof foo>; // type fooReturn = {}

type fooReturn = ReturnType<typeof foo<number>>; // syntax error

type fooReturn = ReturnType<(typeof foo)<number>>; // syntax error
```

Is there a way extract the return type that a generic function would have given  particular type parameters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the return type of a function which uses generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005595/getting-the-return-type-of-a-function-which-uses-generics)

Comment: Small correction, `type fooReturn = ReturnType<typeof foo>; ` yeilds `unknown`.

Comment: Relevant issue in the TypeScript repo: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37181

Comment: Should be possible soon. See [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607) PR

Answer (score -4, accepted):

TypeScript compiler does not see `typeof foo` as generic type. I'd say it's a bug in the compiler.

However, TypeScript has [callable interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types) which can be generic without any problems, so if you introduce a callable interface compatible with the signature of your function, you can implement your own equivalent of `ReturnType` like this:

```
function foo<T>(x: T): T {
  return x;
}


interface Callable<R> {
  (...args: any[]): R;
}

type GenericReturnType<R, X> = X extends Callable<R> ? R : never;

type N = GenericReturnType<number, typeof foo>; // number
```

Comment: The example is pretty useless. You need to know the return type to use `GenericReturnType` to get the return type.

Comment: This is not a good solution because it assumes the function at hand has just one generic type

Comment: Weird that a comment calling it useless has 64 upvotes and the answer has practically no downvotes. It's a convoluted mess that can only return a type that's passed in. `type N = number;` would be exactly the same without all the back and forth.

Answer (score 42):

This was previously impossible to do in a purely generic fashion, but will be in Typescript 4.7. The pattern is called an "Instantiation Expression". The relevant PR is [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47607). Excerpt from the description:

> ````js
> function makeBox<T>(value: T) {
>   return { value };
> };
>
> const makeStringBox = makeBox<string>;  // (value: string) => { value: string }
> const stringBox = makeStringBox('abc');  // { value: string }
>
> const ErrorMap = Map<string, Error>;  // new () => Map<string, Error>
> const errorMap = new ErrorMap();  // Map<string, Error> ```
> ````
>
> ...
>
> A particularly useful pattern is to
> create generic type aliases for applications of `typeof` that reference
> type parameters in type instantiation expressions:
>
> ```js
> type BoxFunc<T> = typeof makeBox<T>;  // (value: T) => { value: T }
> type Box<T> = ReturnType<typeof makeBox<T>>;  // { value: T }
> type StringBox = Box<string>;  // { value: string }
> ```

Comment: I just switched to typescript 4.8 to be able to use this, but it still doesn't appear to work. I'm using react-navigation and am trying to do `type Stack<T extends Record<string, object|undefined>> = ReturnType<typeof createStackNavigator<T>>`. This yields an error though saying "Unexpected token, expected ','" at the `<T>` right after `createStackNavigator`. Doesn't seem to like that syntax.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with react native, but most likely if you're using a tool like expo, its cli is using some other version of typescript.
https://github.com/search?q=typescript+repo%3Aexpo%2Fexpo+filename%3Apackage.json&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l=&l=

Comment: According to `yarn why` at least there's only one version:
yarn why v1.22.17
[1/4]   Why do we have the module "typescript"...?
[2/4]   Initialising dependency graph...
[3/4]   Finding dependency...
[4/4]   Calculating file sizes...
=> Found "typescript@4.8.4"
info Has been hoisted to "typescript"
info This module exists because it's specified in "devDependencies".
info Disk size without dependencies: "68.92MB"
info Disk size with unique dependencies: "68.92MB"
info Disk size with transitive dependencies: "68.92MB"
info Number of shared dependencies: 0
✨  Done in 1.02s.

Comment: Possibly a conflict with the JSX parser, then. See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696475/typescript-tsx-and-generic-parameters

Comment: Good call. It was a JSX parser conflict. To fix it I made a non-generic function that just called the generic function and found the type of that. E.g., `const crapFunction = () => createStackNavigator<SomeParamList>()`. Then, set `type StackType = ReturnType<typeof crapFunction>`. `StackType` will then be the type you want.

Answer (score 41):

This is my currently working solution for extracting un-exported internal types of imported libraries (like knex):

```
// foo is an imported function that I have no control over
function foo<T>(e: T): InternalType<T> {
    return e;
}

class Wrapper<T> {
  // wrapped has no explicit return type so we can infer it
  wrapped(e: T) {
    return foo<T>(e)
  }
}

type FooInternalType<T> = ReturnType<Wrapper<T>['wrapped']>
type Y = FooInternalType<number>
// Y === InternalType<number>
```

Comment: BTW it works if we replace an `interface` with a `class`. Thx for the idea

Comment: Oops! Thanks for calling the mistake out.

Comment: This worked beautifully to type the result of useFormik with the generic parameter intact.

Comment: I want to share my code for a generic formik hook return type as @SørenBoisen noted

`import { FormikConfig, FormikValues, useFormik } from 'formik';`

`class WrappedFormik<Values extends FormikValues = FormikValues> {
formik(config: FormikConfig<Values>) { return useFormik<Values>(config); }
}`

`type Formik<V extends FormikValues = FormikValues> = ReturnType<WrappedFormik<V>['formik']>;`

Answer (score 30):

If you want to get some special generic type, You can use a fake function to wrap it.

```
const wrapperFoo = () => foo<number>()
type Return = ReturnType<typeof wrapperFoo>
```

More complex demo

```
function getList<T>(): {
  list: T[],
  add: (v: T) => void,
  remove: (v: T) => void,
  // ...blahblah
}
const wrapperGetList = () => getList<number>()
type List = ReturnType<typeof wrapperGetList>
// List = {list: number[], add: (v: number) => void, remove: (v: number) => void, ...blahblah}
```

Comment: Also you can use this technique in generic function. 
`function foobar<T> { const wrapperGetList = () => getList<T>(); type List = ReturnType<typeof wrapperGetList>; ... }`

Comment: great solution!

encountered same problem with react hook `useFormik` from `formik` library
i needed to pass typed formik instance as prop to another component. This solution worked:


`const useWrappedFormikForTypes = (...args: any) => useFormik<MyFormValuesType>(args);

export type TypedFormikInstance = ReturnType<typeof useWrappedFormikForTypes>`

Answer (score 8):

I found a good and easy way to achieve this if you can change the function definition.
In my case, I needed to use the typescript type `Parameters` with a generic function, precisely I was trying `Parameters<typeof foo<T>>` and effectively it doesn't work. So the best way to achieve this is changing the ***function definition*** by an ***interface function definition***, this also will work with the typescript type `ReturnType`.

Here an example following the case described by the OP:

```
function foo<T>(e: T): T {
   return e;
}

type fooReturn = ReturnType<typeof foo<number>>; // Damn! it throws error

// BUT if you try defining your function as an interface like this:

interface foo<T>{
   (e: T): T
}

type fooReturn = ReturnType<foo<number>> //it's number, It works!!!
type fooParams = Parameters<foo<string>> //it also works!! it is [string]

//and you can use the interface in this way
const myfoo: foo<number> = (asd: number) => {
    return asd;
};

myfoo(7);
```

Comment: I think `foo` should also be directly callable. `foo(e)` will be error

Comment: This completely defeats the purpose. The entire reason for using `ReturnType` is so that you can derive the return type from a function WITHOUT having to declare an interface that completely duplicates the type. Sure, it works for `number`, but when `foo` returns an object, you don't want to have to create an interface for the complex type.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. You decide if it fits your needs :)

Declare your function args and return type using a interface

```
interface Foo<T, V> {
  (t: T, v: V): [T, V]
}
```

Implement your function this way using `Parameters` and `ReturnType`

```
function foo<T, V>(...[t, v]: Parameters<Foo<T, V>>): ReturnType<Foo<T, V>> {
  return [t, v]; // [T, V]
}
```

Call your function normally, or get return type using `ReturnType`

```
foo(1, 'a') // [number, string]
type Test = ReturnType<Foo<number, number>> // [number, number]
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
const wrapperFoo = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'typescript_helper' ? foo<number>(1) : undefined)!
type Return = typeof wrapperFoo
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&module=5&ssl=8&ssc=32&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAIgAIwJ5gKYGcD0A7CAEwwQG4AocgMwFc8BjGYCPOKiCAHgBUA%20ACgwAuONwCUI7nADe5OPLhQMMGlFYYKAX0r0WWeAHcoAQzCYoAMQ5wAvHH5goEetiwA6DHgBubgHIB5ABEAUQB9YN8ANVsbOwByNEwseihgMBhQgAsMABtzOLgAfjYOTjwaEAAjDCgBAEYxOBE6YipgPAxCMQBCckSMOAAlZVVWO36IKjgjU3MrCCA)

Here's another use case where there is some default type which is not exported.

```js
// Not exported
interface Unaccessible1 {
    z: number
    x: string
}

function foo1<T extends Unaccessible1>(e: T): T {
    return e;
}

const wrapperFoo1 = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'typescript_helper' ? foo1.apply(0, 0 as any) : undefined)!
type ReturnFoo1 = typeof wrapperFoo1 // Unaccessible1

interface Unaccessible2 {
    y: number
    c: string
}

function foo2<T extends Unaccessible2>(e: T, arg2: number, arg3: string, arg4: Function): T {
    return e;
}

const wrapperFoo2 = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'typescript_helper' ? foo2.apply(0, 0 as any) : undefined)!
type ReturnFoo2 = typeof wrapperFoo2 // Unaccessible2
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&module=5&ssl=2&ssc=1&pln=26&pc=1#code/PQgEB4CcFMDNpgOwMbVAFwJ4AdoGcBeAIgAEtc9hEB7AE2iNGAD4AoVgS0XQVgENUoAKqIBqPHg4AjADbQAjKADerUGtAAvAFyhEAVwC2UhKvUAPHXnSQuAc1YBfdrD0p0HaolCxq1eeAAVUGgzHkRaPGFRZHFJWQVmAApoHQCASlTlUzUYdD1IL2gAbkd2ZE8rUAB3SD5sXEgAMV9FAlBE7EhqWIA6aEQANx6AOQB5ABEAUQB9SeGANVACZdAAcnJ8ZBtsdGmAC2gZBtXQAH5vFp667BlMRIAGABpQe9A+SL5ETDTQHVd6WBcaC0NIAQlYG1AACVoHkCs0-EsMDhoNRYNVavUEAjFGARGJ8HE5PJ2FweJB+IJ8TFCdI5AAmLLqUCYHT6IwmZnISzWOylVguNweLw+aj0wLBUL9CJRAkSOnQelJFKgALPPiQWz0tmGYyQdWagDMPJsiFsBtsABYdI1XMh3J4MqqmepcvlCiUnKxyohKjVrtjfIy2h0ur1+kMxlNZgslit1ii8FsODt9odjmcLmKrvVbg9nq93m8vj8-uE4ECQeDITC4YgEcHkbg0RiA00g0xgLKafL4vTWEA)

Comment: This is EXECUTING the function with a hardcoded type and then inferring that type based on the hardcoded value. It doesn't derive anything at all. `type Return = number;` would yield the same type result. But this would need to fill in dummy values for any parameters of `foo` and just live with any side effects it may cause. If `foo` is `db.query`, and your dummy value is `'DROP TABLE Students;'`...

Comment: @EricHaynes when answering my use case was to extract a default type which wasn't exported by some library. Updated my answer to reflect that. I updated the `NODE_ENV` to be a value which clearly reflects the reason for this code and will most probably never execute. And for the dummy values in the second example I'm using `apply`.