# Infer TypeScript type from assignment after declaration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enzyme

When writing tests for React components, it's typical to initialize a component wrapper (say `wrapper`) in a `beforeEach` block and then use it in the subsequent tests. However, in order to do this, you have to declare `wrapper` before its assignment and give it an explicit type or else TypeScript will complain about the lack of a type. Unfortunately, this type can be quite complex to figure out / write out.

In the example below, is there any way to 'delay' TypeScript from complaining about the lack of a type for `wrapper` in the example below and get it to infer the type from the place where `wrapper` is assigned?

Alternatively, is there a better pattern to lay out variables which makes typing easier?

```
describe('suite', () => {
  // will trigger a no implicit any error
  // but it's quite complex to manually write out the type here
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    const SomeElement = complexFunctionWithGenericParams(someParam);

    // ideally, we want TS to infer the type of `wrapper` from this statement
    wrapper = mountComponent(<SomeElement />);
  })

  it('does something', () => {
    expect(wrapper.state.someField).toBe(5);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to infer a type from assignment because it should be inferred at declaration time. The point of local variables in tests is that they can be used between blocks, this means that they can be assigned multiple times. Even if this kind of inference were possible, it would be ambiguous:

```
let foo; // is the type supposed to be a number, or a string, or both, or any?

it('...', () => {
  foo = 1;
});

it('...', () => {
  foo = 'foo';
});
```

So the type should be specified explicitly, e.g. with `ReturnType`:

```
let wrapper: ReturnType<typeof mount>;
```

`mount` is generic, return type may vary, `ReturnType` may be [more complicated with generic functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321419/typescript-returntype-of-generic-function/50321754#50321754).

Since Enzyme `shallow` and `mount` should be explicitly specified with generic parameters:

```
wrapper = mount<typeof SomeElement, ISomeElementProps>(<SomeElement />);
```

It's more straightforward to specify generic type directly, since it's known what type it is (`ReactWrapper`):

```
let wrapper: Enzyme.ReactWrapper<ISomeElementProps, ISomeElementState, typeof SomeElement>
```

Comment: Theoretically, TypeScript _could_ tell that the variable was only assigned in one place and infer a type only if there's a single assignment (not saying whether it _should_ do this or not haha). 


You answer is accurate though and matches what I found. I got stuck at the generic function issue which complicates things; the answer you linked looks potentially helpful though.

Comment: I'd suggest to just specify the type, mount requires to specify generic params any way. I wasn't sure that the question is about Enzyme because it doesn't say this clearly besides a tag, things could be different for other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Although not an entirely different pattern, the following has helped get rid of the said warnings in a similar situation.

```
import { shallow, mount, ReactWrapper } from 'enzyme'

describe('suite', () => {
  let wrapper: ReactWrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
    ...
    wrapper = mount or shallow 
  })

  it('does something', () => {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, agreed that this is a quick way to fix things and partially solves the issue! The downside here is that the props/state of `wrapper` won't be typed