# Typescript ReturnType of function with generic return type

Tags: typescript, generics

Let's say I have a function, which accepts a generic parameter and returns an object which contains this generic paramter:

```js
const wrap = <T>(value: T) => ({ tag: 'XZ' as const, value });
```

The return type of `wrap` is thus: `{ tag: 'XZ', value: T }`.

Is there a way to get that return type using `ReturnType`

Using this approaches does not work, as the generic type gets converted to `unknown`:

```js
type MyType = ReturnType<typeof wrap>
```

Using this approach is not valid Typescript unfortunately:

```js
type MyType<T> = ReturnType<typeof wrap<T>>
```

Is there are way to get a generic return type? I essentially need something like in the last codeblock to work.

I already found [this question&answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321419/typescript-returntype-of-generic-function), but they only extract the generic parameter `T` and not the entire return type of the function with `T` bound to another generic paramter.

Comment: I think the syntax `wrap<T>` being invalid is either a bug or an omission by TypeScript in my opinion. I've had a [similar situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950126/how-to-binding-a-generic-function-in-typescript) where something like `wrap<T>.bind(...)` does not work either when `wrap` is a function.

Comment: Yeah, not possible unfortunately there is no syntax for this