# How to throw interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How pass generic type of Values to ReturnType

```
function Test<Values>(values: Values) {}

interface ExampleProps<Values> {
    values: ReturnType<typeof Test<Values>>; // Compile error <Values>
}
```

Comment: Ask your particular question .

Comment: `values: ReturnType<Test<Values>>;` or maybe `values: ReturnType<Values>; ` ? It is unclear what you are asking exactly...

Comment: Potential duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321419/typescript-returntype-of-generic-function