# How can I get return type of generic functions?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web, react-hooks

I tried to create context that stores return value of `useState` in Typescript like below:

`const SomethingContext = React.createContext<ReturnType<typeof useState<Something>> | undefined>(undefined);`

But it throws a syntax error because of `<Something>` type specification.

If I use `ReturnType` without type specification, `SomethingContext` becomes `React.Context<[unknown, React.Dispatch<unknown>] | undefined>`, which I didn't expected because of `unknown`.

What did I went wrong?

And more in general, how can I get the return type of generic functions with type specified?

#### Expected behavior

A type `GenericReturnType` which satisfies:

`GenericReturnType<Something, useState>` gives `[Something, React.Dispatch<Something>]`

#### Related question

[Typescript ReturnType of generic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321419/typescript-returntype-of-generic-function)

Comment: I love this as well for my use case: `function useMyHook(): ReturnType<typeof useState<string>> { ... };`

Answer (score 1):

First, `useState` is not a type at all, It cannot be passed in the way of generic, thus, it's not realistic to `GenericReturnType<Something, useState>` into `[Something | undefined, React.Dispatch<Something>]`

Second, the type of `useState<T>()` is equal to `[T, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>]`, I am curious why you do not use `React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>` directly instead?

Comment: I'm looking for the answer to same question, but it seems not possible. But as I came here, I saw you asked why not use something like  `function useMyHook(): [string, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>]`. Well, first that does not read good, and second I want to be safe against future library changes. So if in future the return type of `useState` changes, I don't have to change my code as well. Also I have installed the library so I don't have to write code myself. Type definitions follow the same rule. the type exists in the library, so I shouldn't write it myself again.

Comment: I prefer something like: `function useMyHook(): ReturnType<typeof useState<string>>` which reads way better: `Whatever the useState with string returns`