# Strongly Type ReturnType of Generic Function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript-generics

Trying to strongly type the return type of a generic function, where that function returns an object whose values are based off that generic

```
function val<T>() {
    function update(id: T): T {
        return id;
    }
    return {
        update,
    };
}
type a = ReturnType<typeof val>;
```

Ie. how does one get 'a' below to show detailed return type? (ie not show unknowns as in the picture attached)

[image]

**EDITS**

My example is most like [this item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62620115/4677615) in the similar post linked in the comments. My difficulty is that my function is a hook so afaik I can't wrap it like this? Right now my only way around this seems to be manually declaring an interface but I'd rather have some typescript voodoo implicitly derive the ReturnType for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript ReturnType of generic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321419/typescript-returntype-of-generic-function)

Comment: Also, the current return is as detailed as it's going to get unless you do something like `const typedVal = () => val<string>();` and `ReturnType<typeof typedVal>`.

Comment: What "detailed return type" are you expecting? `val` is a generic function, but the output of `val()` isn't: it is not `<T>(id: T)=>T`. Instead, it should be `<∃T>(id: T) => T` where `∃T` represents an *existentially quantified generic type parameter* as requested in [ms/TS#14466](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466), but that is not part of the language. You can think of it like "the infinite union of all functions of the form `(id: T) => T`"... the closest thing in TS that exists is `(id: never) => unknown`. Neither of these are particularly useful types, so what's the use case?