# Incorrect return type for conditional generics

Tags: typescript

I'm attempting to write a function that returns a value using generics and conditional types like so:

```
interface Foo<T> {
  bar: T extends true ? string : undefined;
  id: string;
}

interface Options<T> {
  withBar?: T;
}

function createFoo<T extends boolean>({ withBar }: Options<T>): Foo<T> {
  return {
    id: 'foo',
    ...(withBar && { bar: 'baz' }),
  };
}
```

The above throws the following type error:

```
Type '{ bar?: "baz" | undefined; id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Foo<T>'.
  Types of property 'bar' are incompatible.
    Type '"baz" | undefined' is not assignable to type 'T extends true ? string : undefined'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'T extends true ? string : undefined'.
```

Can someone help me understand why this is the case? I'm specifying that the type can be undefined, so it should be allow to be undefined.

Additionally I'd like to get the return type of the function given certain params without actually calling it. Is that possible?

e.g. `ReturnType<typeof createFoo>` won't give me the correct type for usage `createFoo({ withBar: true })` because it doesn't know about the usage yet.

[Live example here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4AqA%20ZAbwChlkAjOKALmR2QgA9IQATAZ2TCgFcUB%20ZO26gA5slo82EGKAisA3KWTBWtYVDFKAvsWKhIsRCgDyABzDB0IdrgIkyAd2BgAFgCEq-Wjh16YUgiW1sgIUBBwkBjY9EwsHBSYADYRIHgAFITIzm6eUMjatObBNnYAlLTRdkTK4WA8UCA1ZGSqtADkMJjtADTKZAB0Q%20k5HlTIAGQTRBRUHZQAXu0FZX1k2n5AA)

Comment: _"I'm specifying that the type can be undefined, so it should be allow to be undefined."_ well... your specificying that in one a specific case it's undefined, and Typescript can't be sure your code makes sure that specific case is handled by the logic of your function. Typescript has a hard time validating that the logic of your function satisfies the contract of a conditional return type. That's pretty tough for the compiler to track since it doesn't really execute your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem, the generic types do not resolve inside the function implementation. You could write a function overload to make your implementation work:

```
interface Foo<T> {
  bar: T extends true ? string : undefined;
  id: string;
}

interface Options<T> {
  withBar?: T;
}

function createFoo<T extends boolean>({ withBar }: Options<T>): Foo<T>
function createFoo({ withBar }: Options<boolean>): Foo<true> | Foo<false> {
  // The implementation works because the return type is allowed to be Foo<true> or Foo<false>
  return {
    id: 'foo',
    ...(withBar && { bar: 'baz' }),
  };
}

// The first function overload is taken because it's the first one to match
// the call parameters
const foo = createFoo({ withBar: false }); // foo is of type Foo<false>
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&filetype=ts#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-gCkSjVkA)

Comment: Do you know why using `Object.assign` works in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70384234/438273) where spread syntax doesn't?

Comment: @jsejcksn `Object.assign` copies enumerable own properties from the second argument. The value `false` (the value/type of `withBar && xyz` if `withBar` is false) doesn't have any of those, so JS effectively does nothing with it without erroring. The type signature just creates an intersection of the arguments, so TS is fine with it. Spread operates on iterables, so TS will type error since `false` isn't iterable.

Comment: Awesome! How would I go about getting the return type given one of the scenarios? e.g. `type Baz = ReturnType<typeof createFoo>;` I can't pass the generics in there. Given my real world scenario I'm also trying to avoid using the `Foo` type with generics.

Comment: This evaluates to `Foo<boolean>` isn't it what you expect?

Comment: Yes but how would I use my syntax in a way to get the same as `Foo<true>`? I can't do `type Baz = ReturnType<typeof createFoo>;` then `type Bam = Baz<true>` can I?

Comment: I don't know but there is an answer about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321419/typescript-returntype-of-generic-function

Answer (score 1):

There's an important distinction between a required property than can hold a value or `undefined` (the key is always present), and an optional property (the key might not be in the object at all). See [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/#exact-optional-property-types)

In your post, you typed `bar` on `Foo` as always being present, with a conditional value of `string` or `undefined`, but you were returning an object which only conditionally had the `bar` key at all.

In the modification below, I retyped `Foo` to reflect an optional property type  for `bar` based on the same boolean condition.

I also replaced the spread operator syntax with `Object.assign` (satisfied the compiler), however, I'm not sure why this makes a difference.

Also, noteworthy: TS complains if you try to spread a non-object type into an object (e.g. `undefined` in your post):

```ts
const obj = {...undefined};
/*           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Spread types may only be created from object types.(2698) */
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAEEsDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrUAxA9tgPACoB8oA3gFAijUBGy8AXKAaLAB5yQAmAzqNPACuGAPygeAqAHNQTQd1iIosLgG5KYauC5MJ8aeqoBfcuWgBPAA4YAypMhSAkl1ABeMhB3j7Mo+rNWGDj4xG7MrByw3HwCwqBidvoOzqAAZB50jN5JvrKgidLO-lBwSGgYAPKW0ODYkDyEJBTUAO7g0AAWAEL0IkwE6ibkiPKoNXWgqPCwyHDBjQAUpKBtnT3woEZMVeP1jQCUTPOhzaBU09CC8JBk5NRUWl4A5Ii4TwA0d2eaoAB0-wtVt16Gl0stMkwnnQAF5PTb7T73MB+L4XK43Co0ABWsDGv2QPB44CkkCW2khr2wTyM71AgPawI2qTBoAhoChyFh8P2g1MqDqPGwABtYL8hdgpAspjM5rglkD1kxYrAjPsed8POTQAAiSna2ls7Uw7Wbcj8+rC0XiyXS2awYLyhmK0AoIU8FVq1Qa5Za3W4E0mc2CkViiVS6Z2h2kVXqqg+rx+7AB8hAA)

```ts
type StringId = { id: string };

type Foo<T> = T extends true ? StringId & { bar: string } : StringId;

interface Options<T> {
  withBar?: T;
}

function createFoo<T>({ withBar }: Options<T>): Foo<T> {
  return Object.assign({id: 'foo'}, (withBar && { bar: 'baz' }));
}

console.log(createFoo({withBar: true})); // { id: "foo", bar: "baz" }
console.log(createFoo({withBar: false})); // { id: "foo" }
console.log(createFoo({})); // { id: "foo" }
```

> Additionally I'd like to get the return type of the function given certain params without actually calling it. Is that possible?

Yes, by adding a conditional return type to the function, which depends on the parameter:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=14&ssc=54&pln=7&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwJIBMoF4oG8pFMAuKAZwRVSgF8BuAKEdEigDEB7TgHgBUoEAB7AIyTOSgAjbgBsIAQ2QA+XFAHDR4yQgCu0APywqaLFABkBaQvhlKSNHShk4DjJiaMUo+ADMFAMbQAPJgwIicyOT8qviMUFAA7ojAABYAQjYGZHxMtMy+usgB4ZFQAfCKoly8GiJiEtJyiioAFITJaZnwdGShpVExAJQ5gvXaUHqGHNw8U6pkNTz+suQQsfFQlcC68MhQwVIAVhAlAHQK5OSIqMjtxGQA5L7cj7QANFCtnRk2FpaEKQ2J5AgBejzoQyGeWYAUilCgL04AEY1BUqhAau0ft0yFNaNCoAB6InGNxmAHWWwUEw0fJwqLARHcABMaMqCmq3GxKV+1JWawJ9GJpNc1CwBU4PVaDIRSKgnF8UAA2kjkZ8kSyALpDcrwzjyM6yTioVpI6GMIA)

```ts
function createFoo<T extends boolean>({ withBar }: Options<T>): T extends true ? Foo<true> : Foo<false> {
  return Object.assign({id: 'foo'}, (withBar && { bar: 'baz' }));
}

const foo1 = createFoo({withBar: true}); // StringId & { bar: string }
const foo2 = createFoo({withBar: false}); // StringId
```

Comment: Thanks for the [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70383778/incorrect-return-type-for-conditional-generics/70383906?noredirect=1#comment124418237_70383906) @chrisbajorin