# Extract react component prop types with generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

Is there a way to use react's `ComponentProps` type with generic-typed components?

For example:

```
function MyComponent<T extends string, N extends number>({ text, number }: { text: T; number: N }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {text} - {number}
    </div>
  );
}

export type MyComponentProps = ComponentProps<typeof MyComponent>;
```

I expect `MyComponentProps` to be something like...

```
type MyComponentPropsExpected<T extends string, N extends number> = {
    text: T;
    number: N;
}
```

With the generics preserved. However, the type just drops the generic and fills all generics with their `extends` type. In this case the actual `MyComponentProps` type is...

```
type MyComponentProps = {
    text: string;
    number: number;
}
```

See demo [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiTAApQRgDOcAvnAGY0hwBEUqGnA3AChBLAK4kMwUnACyAT0LEyFADwAVOEgAeMcgBMGdGFGAkA5tgBymnfoYlRIAEZIoAPgAUOQXDi6dmD5wDs6ugowAXLhB-jBRakK%20IS5QUZZCjACU0b48MKJQJHAeQb4qesAAbm6lvrixzAC0uMmujLUqAPQV1UGZGcIwcmBIsgpEkMpUNPRwALwEE6Tk07R0KkMjECxjipMrbkKCm6Pye8sU1GsAolojGEh66ja6JAZwRibmVi92wY4pNzzHJ%20bRxOAJIKtVJwdLhI7aSCwOBoUhGUFGACMUTOSymV3ot3uuienFinGwACYgQtvL5YlEyWCKVCAa4opT4cJOp04AAxFDAAA2dEEiOg8FRJHRuiMlJx4yUKwJ6yZOgpcGpwLpoJ0jPJgSSbJhnMYQiAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

`MyComponent` has two type parameters `T` and `N` with each constrained to `string` and `number` respectively:

```
function MyComponent<T extends string, N extends number>(...) { ... }
```

However when the `MyComponentProps` type is created, no types are passed into those parameters:

```
export type MyComponentProps = ComponentProps<typeof MyComponent>;
//                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ 
//                                           No type arguments passed in
```

As a result, the resultant type is the type of the constrained component props.

## Solution

### TypeScript >=4.7

You'll need to pass in types to `MyComponent`:

```
type MyComponentProps = ComponentProps<typeof MyComponent<"text", 2>>;
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiTAApQRgDOcAvnAGY0hwBEUqGnA3AChBLAK4kMwUnACyAT0LEyFADwAVOEgAeMcgBMGdGFGAkA5tgBymnfoYlRIAEZIoAPgAUOQXDi6dmD5wDs6ugowAXLhB-jBRakK+IS5QUZZCjACU0b48MKJQJHAeQb4qesAAbm6lvrixzAC0uMmujLUqAPQV1UGZGcIwcmBIsgpEkMpUNPRwALwEE6Tk07R0KkMjECxjipMrKpyxnNgATG5uQoKbo-J7yxTUawCiWiMYSHrqNrokBnBGEzmKw-OzBRwpNzzHJ+bRxOAJIKtVJwdLhK7aSCwOBoUhGWFGACMUTuSymT3or3eui+RzhJzg52h3l8sSidJ0JyRENcUVO6OEnU6cAAYihgAAbOiCTHQeC4kj43RGU4k8ZKFYUhgLFmwnTs46BJI8lH8xhCIA)

However, this syntax is only available in TypeScript 4.7+, when [instantiation expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) were introduced.

### TypeScript <4.7

Prior to TypeScript 4.7, I would have pulled out the props into its own interface and used that instead of building a type from `ComponentProps`:

```
interface MyComponentProps<T extends string, N extends number> {
  text: T;
  number: N;
}

function MyComponent<T extends string, N extends number>({
  text,
  number
}: MyComponentProps<T, N>) {
  ...
}

export const test2: MyComponentProps<"text", 2> = {
  text: "text",
  number: 2
};
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiTAApQRgDOcAvnAGY0hwBEUqGnA3AChBwCkigt0SOAFkAnoWJkK1WnQA8AFThIAHjHIATBnRhRRAc2wA5HfqMMSAVxAAjcQD5cguHAP6ALjhNIV9nN3Eg6yFGYRYnEgxgUlkFIkhlGC07AxJjOFNzEis4Wz1c-PD3KA8AChwfP3LMRqrxQUYg+UUM8ioaei0bDwBKb18eGCcoEjhaxt91Q2AANw8F31x-GGYAWlw2qFjNuHUAemW1xpGY4Rg5MGlu9NI+1XoAUV1HjCRDbPKDgKZksNhyQMOXgAvOMmoFgqE4IcojEhII9JBYHA0KRTE1TABGLppJRvAZ0L4-Az-TjbTjYABM0Nh2yCtPK9NaLmqQQZHTRZzOcAAYihgAAbOjo77QeA4kh4gymBnEnqvFTk9Ts-T0uBMuAwhq+VlcOktMLcyJ6-mCIA)

## Further reading

- [Typescript ReturnType of generic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321419/typescript-returntype-of-generic-function)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! This solves my issue. Unfortunately the second option doesn't work for my case cuz I am using a complex component factory to generate the component. Do you think it would be possible to modify the [`ComponentProps`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/0096577e5a57944e0e1fb5ac71dee1187147bf09/types/react/v17/index.d.ts#L828-L833) type from `@types/react` to extract the full type with generics?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think so. The crux of the issue is the ability to pass type arguments into the generic. Would moving the type parameters from your component to the component factory be acceptable? [Example](https://tsplay.dev/NnKyxm).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, not really because the factory generics could vary widely between components. But using the TS >=4.7 approach is not the worst thing. Thanks again!