# Mapping each field of a record in a type-safe manner

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a curried function that will map each field of a record in a type-safe manner. I can't figure out how can I use a mapped type and take into account the cases when field mapping function (`fn: TFunc`) may be generic or overloaded:

[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&noUnusedLocals=true&target=99&jsx=0&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&ssl=16&ssc=113&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLYEMwCVhJQAmAYgJbAA2RqcAvHADwAqJArsgnKDMMjXAAUIAFxwsyAJ4BKegD5xUhYICwAKDhwAZsjGsOCADRwA9CbiReyGGSyVKkuAHM+wKGS7Q4EAG5vKEFhEwETaBjYo6rJ0Ciz4hKE8fALx0ESM6O7ITsYcANbIEADuyHLK6ppQBGl6qcSGUWIA3nAA2gAKcGTIcHnAkhBacMx1RAC6YiYAVHAA-PNwU+YAvvJwLdMWlLRkToVVXRhglMAYfDBYET2X4vaLKwDc6upIaPBkwdZkMI4MLHLCPTSPRrEBPNSvdBwGAQADK3ScJwAoicztYAIJQKD0JjMAGiYbAtrMMZrVogMbPCEoKGZNgIGBsA4MJoVOAEgCMDQ0cEkYgA5ABHIrAfnc1ZYWiQmDgl40+BVVBsSgwDk47B4arEchUGiCD7nb4yQR0hlM4DSB6mcygMAEXihbpaNxVUI-O1wAC0605xj5cCFIv5yzlbzgiuVMAATOqcKMddRUIIYfDssjUedMVBpCaYFB6YyqpbrdxwPaQl1kM6sRX3cAvT6xK0OWM-U3A6KxssgA)

```
export const mapRecordFields = <TFunc extends (x: any) => any> (
  fn: TFunc, // potentially generic or overloaded function
) => <TRecord extends Record<string, any>> (
  record: TRecord,
): { [P in keyof TRecord]: /* ??? */ } => { /* pls ignore implementation at all */ };

const identity = <T> (x: T): T => x;
const toSingleElementArr = <T> (x: T): [T] => [x]

const structure = {
  x: 1,
  y: 'qwe',
} as const;

const result1 = mapRecordFields(identity)(structure); // expected inferred type - {x: 1, y: 'qwe'}
const result2 = mapRecordFields(toSingleElementArr)(structure); // expected inferred type - {x: [1], y: ['qwe']}
```

I couldn't make inferred type for a `result` to be `{x: 1, y: 'qwe'}` despite reading and trying various answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760509/typescript-returntype-of-overloaded-function/60822641#60822641) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321419/typescript-returntype-of-generic-function). Is there any way to make it work?